# How to connect to .ui forms?

Tags: qt4

I am a begginer in qt i am facing a prob in connecting two .ui forms.
Means i have a main window and a button on that "next" i want to connect a another form with this button.
Simply i want clicking on next button will redirect to the other form.
How it should done?
Guide me.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027406/how-to-move-to-another-window-in-qt-by-a-pushbutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main window's class, create a slot that is run when the next button is pressed.  In that slot, create your new window and show it, then hide the main window.

Comment: thanks for above but i have two .ui files and i want to connect them with a button simply clicking on button take the user to the other form(which is other .ui file)